# Path to midpoint of other path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to end a path at the midpoint of another path. My inclination has been to try and end the path at an offset equal to half the node distance from `d.north`, but any thing I seem to try will not compile. Here's what I have so far (the end goal being the 'No' path ending at 'HERE' )

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}    

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, draw]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [box] (a) {A};
    \node [box, below of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [box, below of=b] (c) {C};
    \node [box, below of=c] (d) {D};

       % Draw edges
    \path [line] (a) -- (b);
    \path [line] (b) -- (c);
    \path [line] (c) -- node [midway, left] {HERE} (d);

   \path [line] (a.east) --node [above] {No}  +(1,0) |- (d.north);     

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above code]

I've seen some things on path decorations, but I'm really unsure how to use them and not sure that I can end the path on them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code already contains a solution (without `calc` library): `midway`!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, draw]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [box] (a) {A};
    \node [box, below of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [box, below of=b] (c) {C};
    \node [box, below of=c] (d) {D};

       % Draw edges
    \path [line] (a) -- (b);
    \path [line] (b) -- (c);
    \path [line] (c) -- coordinate[midway](m) (d);

   \path [line] (a.east) --node [above] {No}  +(1,0) |- (m);     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ha! Simplicity above all.

Comment: That's awesome. I think I'll switch to this because I know it'll be easier to read/relearn when I come back to these diagrams in a few months.

Comment: @blitzvergnugen Don't forget that `midway` is in fact `pos=.5`...

Answer (score 19):

Like this? `(c)!0.5!(d)` means halfway between `(c)` and `(d)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}    

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, draw]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [box] (a) {A};
    \node [box, below of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [box, below of=b] (c) {C};
    \node [box, below of=c] (d) {D};

       % Draw edges
    \path [line] (a) -- (b);
    \path [line] (b) -- (c);
    \path [line] (c) -- node [midway, left] {HERE} (d);

   \path[line] let \p1 = ( $(c)!0.5!(d) $ ) in (a.east) --node [above] {No}  +(1,0) |- +(0,\y1);     

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works great! I changed it to `\path [line] (a.east) --node [above] {No}  +(1,0) |- ( $(c)!0.5!(d) $ );` because I wanted it to actually touch the line.

Comment: A couple follow up questions if you don't mind. The `\y1` does that reference the y-coordinate of `a.east`? And can you reference `\p1` outside of that line?

Comment: @blitzvergnugen `\p1` "holds" the coordinates of `(c)!0.5!(d)`; the x-coordinate can be retrieved using `\x1`, and the y-ccordinate, using `\y1`. The definition is local; but you could use macros to store the values globally.

Comment: @blitzvergnugen to extract coordinates you could also use the `\pgfextractx`, `\pgfextracty` macros (see Section 70.6 of the `pgfmanual`).